# How to setup Paypal subscriptions with multiple currencies?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

For each product we do the following:

1. When a new product is added, create a new Product with `POST /v1/catalogs/products`
2. Using the `product_id` from step 1, create a new plan `POST /v1/billing/plans`
3. Whenever a customer clicks "Subscribe" button, we create a new subscription using `plan_id` from step 2 with `POST /v1/billing/subscriptions`

**Problem:** When creating the subscription we are able to change the price the customer will be billed by passing the `plan` object to `POST /v1/billing/subscriptions` endpoint to override the amount of the plan. However passing in a different currency throws an error:

```
"The currency code is different from the plan's currency code."
```

With that being said, **is there a way to setup paypal subscriptions where we can pass in a different currency**? Is it required to create a new plan for each currency because this does not seem like a good solution

We create a billing plan with the following body:

```js
{
                            product_id: productId,
                            name: planName,
                            status: 'ACTIVE',
                            billing_cycles: [
                                {
                                    frequency: {
                                        interval_unit: 'MONTH',
                                        interval_count: 1
                                    },
                                    tenure_type: 'REGULAR',
                                    sequence: 1,
                                    // Create a temporary pricing_scheme. This will be replaced
                                    // with a variable amount when a subscription is created.
                                    pricing_scheme: {
                                        fixed_price: {
                                            value: '1',
                                            currency_code: 'CAD'
                                        }
                                    },
                                    total_cycles: 0
                                }
                            ],
                            payment_preferences: {
                                auto_bill_outstanding: true,
                                payment_failure_threshold: 2
                            }
                        }
```

We create subscription with the following body (however passing in a different currency than the plan (CAD) throws an error):

```js
{
        plan_id: planId,
        subscriber: {
            email_address: email
        },
        plan: {
            billing_cycles: [
                {
                    sequence: 1,
                    pricing_scheme: {
                        fixed_price: {
                            value: amount,
                            currency_code: currency
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        custom_id: productId
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it required to create a new plan for each currency

Yes

Comment: We were hesitant on that solution because it means for each product we would have 25+ plans, and whenever a new product is created we would have to make a request to paypal 25+ times, while also keeping track of the which plan a currency belongs to for each product. Is there no other way around this?